# Python Flask Requests 400 Error Code

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, flask-restful

I'm catching a POST request from requests to flask-rest and I keep getting a 400 error code (Bad Request).

**Requests Part:**

```
def send_data(asset_id, data1, data2, data3):
    global _server_api
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    complete_url = _server_api + asset_id
    payload = {'d1': data1,'d2': data2,'d3': data3}
    response = requests.post(complete_url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

**Flask Part:**

```
from flask.ext.restful.representations.json import output_json
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import reqparse, abort, Api, Resource
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
assets = {}
class Broker(Resource): 
   def post(self, asset_id):
       assets[asset_id] = dict()
       data1 = request.form['d1']
       data2 = request.form['d2']
       data3 = request.form['d3']
       assets[asset_id]['d1'] = request.form['d1']
       assets[asset_id]['d2'] = request.form['d2']
       assets[asset_id]['d3'] = request.form['d3']
       collector(asset_id, data1, data2, data3) #<--- writes to DB
       return {asset_id: assets[asset_id]}

api.add_resource(Broker, '/api-v1.0/add/<string:asset_id>', methods=['PUT', 'POST', 'GET'])
```

**Error Code:**

```
{u'status': 400, u'message': u'Bad Request'}
```

I keep getting a 400 Error code when the requests part makes the call to the API.

When changing the *request.form* to *request.get_json* I get a error as below .

```
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sending a JSON request, but the app expects a form. Instead of `request.form` use `request.get_json()` in the app.

Comment: I get the following error when I change all to request.get_jason() in the app.

TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: I was using the get_jason() incorrectly and see it needs to be captured and the paramrs extracted using standard dict method. .myvar['myparam']